# MediaPortal crash when scanning my TV Channels

Tags: windows-xp, mediaportal

I tried installing [MediaPortal](http://www.team-mediaportal.com) on my old system. I installed & tried both beta & stable releases:

Here's the old system specs:

```
Windows XP SP3

512MB DDR

80GB IDE

K-World PVR-TV7131 Analog TV-Tuner

Inno3d FX5500 128MB 64bit
```

When scanning through the TV-Server, it crashes. I don't know if the incompatibility comes from the hardware or the OS, but my TV Tuner's own Media center app works well. For now, that's what im using.

Anyone here familiar with MediaPortal? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your K-World PVR-TV7131 might not be supported by MediaPortal. Though their wiki is down (and has been down for awhile), I believe I have never come across a K-World card before in the supported hardware listing before.

Have you tried some of the other media center projects like [MythTV](http://www.mythtv.org/)? If you can get MythTV to work, then you know that MediaPortal is not compatible with your K-World card.

Comment: after reading posts about MythTV on Windows, I decided not to burden myself of the same problems other people had with it. Do you know any other free Media Center alternatives (not necessarily opensource, i don't need to modify the code anyway).

Thanks caliban! (PS you name reminds me of a character in X-Force).

Comment: @Martin Ongtangco : -laughs- it requires work to get a Media Center to run properly. Anyway, you can try GB-PVR http://www.gbpvr.com/, or, what I really recommend - Windows Media Center on Windows 7 Ultimate (go download the trial version). It's really a fantastic experience, and MCE w/ Windows 7 is a matured, grown-up product.

Comment: @Martin Ongtango : Caliban's a popular name name for many literary / entertainment works, and it is originally the name for a character in the Shakespeare play *The Tempest*.

Comment: Link to download Windows 7 Enterprise 90-day trial : http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/springboard/archive/2009/09/01/windows-7-enterprise-90-day-evaluation-now-available.aspx comes with the new, rockin' MCE.

Comment: good luck, and don't giving up getting your Media Center done up the way you want! It takes effort initially, but once you set it up the way you want, you'll be able to sit back and bask in the rewards of your efforts.